# Modulus/Remainder function for non-integers

Tags: haskell, floating-point, modulo

rem gives this:

```
Prelude> rem 9 8
1
```

I wanted something like this:

```
Prelude> nonIntRem 9.1 8
1.0999999999999996
```

I implemented it like this:

```
nonIntRem x y = x - (y * (fromIntegral $ truncate (x/y)))
```

My questions are:

1. Does something like this already exist in a standard Haskell library? I'd prefer to use a standard function, and I may have missed it.
2. If not, is there a more standard name for this function in other languages? Maybe fmod, but the behavior for negatives in this case is not like mod, but like rem. If there is no standard name, can you think of a better name for this function?
3. It seems to work properly, but if you notice a problem with this function, I'd like to know about it.

Comment: Yeah, `fmod` is C's name for it, so `frem` seems like a logical extension

Comment: Also, `toInteger` is the only thing preventing the floating point types from being an instance of `Integral`... if you are okay with that hole, maybe just instantiate it and then you can call it `rem` (implement `quotRem` and you get all the floating div/mods).

Answer (score 23):

The function you're after is [`mod'`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Fixed.html#v:mod-39-) from `Data.Fixed`.

Comment: Yes, this is close. However, this has the mod behavior for negatives, while my function has the rem behavior for negatives.Prelude Data.Fixed> mod' 9.1 (-8)
-6.9
Prelude Data.Fixed> nonIntRem 9.1 (-8)
1.0999999999999996