# Haskell - Instance of Integral Float required for definition of unSum x = (y + y`mod`2 + 2) / 2 where y = x*(x+1) / 2

Tags: haskell

The Following code:

```
unSum :: Float -> Float
unSum x = (y + y`mod`2 + 2) / 2
        where
        y = x*(x+1) / 2
```

gives me this error when I try to load it into WinHugs 98:

```
Hugs> :load "D:\\kram\\unSumme2.hs"
ERROR file:.\unSumme2.hs:2 - Instance of Integral Float required for definition of unSumme2
```

What's the essence of this and how am I to do it? Anyway, I dont now if it serves my porpuse,  I want to calculate the sum of the uneven numbers until x without recursivity.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're using `mod`. The definition of `mod`, from the [Standard Prelude](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html):

```
class  (Real a, Enum a) => Integral a  where
[...]
div, mod         :: a -> a -> a
[...]
n `mod` d        =  r  where (q,r) = divMod n d
```

In other words, it expects `a` to be of the numeric typeclass Integral, which includes only whole numbers.

If you want to stick with `Float`s, try using [`mod'`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Fixed.html#v%3amod-39-), from `Data.Fixed`, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027865/modulus-remainder-function-for-non-integers).

Alternatively, if you just want to do integer division, you could change your function's signature to

```
unSum :: Int -> Int
```

or similar.