# Does Haskell have an equivalent of Ruby's (and others) % (mod) operator?

Tags: ruby, haskell, math

Ruby's mod operator (%) is defined as a floored division:

```
x.modulo(y) means x-y*(x/y).floor
```

This gives results like:

```
irb(main):001:0> -0.5 % 2
=> 1.5
```

Does Haskell have a built in equivalent operator/function?

So far I can only find reference to mod, divMod, rem and the like, all of which only seem to operate on Integral types, or am I missing something?

At the moment I've just defined a function:

```
fmod :: Float -> Float -> Float
fmod a b = a - b * fromIntegral(floor (a/b))
```

But I'd like to use something built in if available.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027865/modulus-remainder-function-for-non-integers

Comment: @AJFarmar thanks, funny how many times using different words gets the correct answer. :-)